# Checking if string is not specific value

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

```
if((... && ev.target.id !== "dragPos"){
```

How do you correctly check if ev.target.id is not the same as "dragPos"?

Comment: Does the code you posted not work?

Comment: What you have should work just fine. What problem are you having?

Comment: You have an extra opening parenthesis, but we don't know what's at the start. right now you're comparing ev.target.id to the literal string "dragPos" if you have a variable named dragPos, remove the quotation marks to reference it

Comment: the extra parenthesis is because of another condition at the beginning.

Comment: So, as other posters have suggested, the expression `ev.target.id !== "dragPos"` should work just fine, and is a valid way to confirm that whatever value is stored at `ev.target.id` does not equal the string `"dragPos"`. So, again, what is the _specific_ problem you are having?

Answer (score -1):

```
    var string = "foo", substring = "oo";
 string.indexOf(substring) !== -1;
```

Comment: String.prototype.indexOf returns the position of the string in the other string. If not found, it will return -1

Comment: So, this is a valid way to check if one string is _contained_ in another string, but not a valid way to check if the strings are not equal to each other, which is what the question poses.

Answer (score -3):

The different sign is !=, not !==
Enclose your condition in parenthesis for safety

if((... && (ev.target.id != "dragPos")){

Comment: `!==` is "not equal" with strong type checking in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Nonidentity